# Can not use gems after install RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm using Arch Linux with Zsh.
I installed RVM follow the official document :

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

After installed RVM. Every gem I installed show me the *Gem::LoadError* error like this :

```
$ gem install huami
$ huami
/home/meck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find huami (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/meck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/meck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /home/meck/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/huami:22:in `<main>'
```

And gem list is empty :

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

This is my gem env :

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 320) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/meck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/meck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/meck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/meck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/"]
     - "gem" => "--user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Could anybody point out what step did I miss?

Comment: Try `rvm do gem install huami`.

Comment: you are using "gem" => "--user-install" did you try installing gems without this setting?

Comment: Are you using oh-my-zsh?

Comment: @Andrea Salicetti Tried, did not work for me.

Comment: @Remear Yes, I'm using on-my-zsh。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM doesn't work very will with oh-my-zsh. oh-my-zsh likes to control a lot of your shell experience. Your mileage will vary. Certain extensions will conflict with RVM's operation. Hop in IRC Freenode #rvm if you encounter issues as they can provide direct and quick help with oh-my-zsh.

Comment: i think @Meck should have came back and give the proper answer